# Multiple @Transactional annotation over more than 2 methods not working

Tags: spring, jpa, transactions

I have two methods for my transactions, like below

```
Class MyTransaction(){

@Transactional
public void initialTranx(){

  String userId = 500;
  // do some user specific activity
 updateUserBalance(500);
  // check user balance
}

@Transactional
private void updateUserBalance(int userId){
 // codes for updating balance to 400
}

}
```

Now am calling initialTranx() method, this method internally calls private method updateUserBalance(userid), but balance is not getting updated after my updateUserBalance method executes. Only after completing public method(parent method) transaction getting committed.

I need to commit my second method's transaction, after completing private method itself.

I am using mysql for DB and spring data JPA.

Please some one guide me on this.

Answer (score 5):

1. `@Transactional` does not work on private methods, use public. Depending on class proxy strategy, calling a method in the same class may not trigger a transaction either.
2. JPA does not officially support nested transactions. It may [work with Spring to some extent](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/JpaTransactionManager.html), but strange errors can happen.
3. If you want to force changes to database before transaction is committed, you can use [EntityManager.flush()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#flush()).

Comment: This is a good answer.  One suggestion to improve it: another option is to use [programmatic transaction management](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#transaction-programmatic).  This would address #1 but some additional refactoring would be required to address #2.

Answer (score 0):

Use em.flush() isn't a good practice. I suggest you to use a propagation feature. See [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html)

```
public class ServiceClass {

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void updateUserBalance(int userId){
        // codes for updating balance to 400
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried   @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) in my public method, but it is not working..Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

This approach wouldn't work for two methods within same class because when initialTranx invokes updateUserBalance then it invokes this method on target object rather than proxy object. If you move updateUserBalance to a separate class then it will work with 
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)